# Creating Non-earth custom projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am trying to create a local mine grid custom projection. I asked our survey team but they do not know. Below is the only information I know.

[image]

The UTM is in Zone 38N. The local mine grid is also tilted -14.5 deg true N. No tilting in Z.

Please help in the codes.

Comment: is the mine on earth or some other planet

Comment: According to the title it is not on earth.

Comment: no its not......

Comment: So the starting point cannot be UTM which is Earth bound

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: nmtoken
do you understand when I say non-earth? Did you use Mapinfo?

Comment: A non-earth projection does not mean a different planet - it means a local grid with no direct connection to WGS84.  @Mikx Montes - please ignore these commenters, your question is clear that you need to relate a local grid to WGS84.  This link here is also relevant: [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/404614/is-there-a-generally-accepted-or-best-practice-for-creating-a-prj-file-to-define)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTM 38N
CM = 45E

UTMX0 =  379741.5
UTMY0 = 2004139.0

LON0 = 43.863285
LAT0 = 18.122765

delta lambda = LON0-CM = -1.136715
SIN (LAT0) = 0.311054068

UTM GRID convergence = (LON0-CM)* SIN(LAT0) = -0.353579825

MINING ANGLE (True North) = -14.5

MINING ANGLE (Grid North)
= MINING ANGLE (True North) - UTM GRID convergence
= -14.5 + 0.353579825
= -14.14642018

Calculated Pairs using simple geometry

nr Mx  My  UTMx    UTMy
UR 5800    3000    379741.50   2004139.00
LL 0   0   374850.59   1999812.45
LR 5800    0   380474.70   2001229.98
UL 0   3000    374117.39   2002721.48

install "Geoscience" plugin in QGIS
Go to Geoscience > Create local CRS
enter the four calculated points
press  Calculate

Go to Settings > Custom Projections
paste the text below

DERIVEDPROJCRS["Mining grid",BASEPROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 38N",BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],ID["EPSG",4326]],CONVERSION["UTM zone 38N",METHOD["Transverse Mercator",ID["EPSG",9807]],PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8801]],PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",45,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8802]],PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,SCALEUNIT["unity",1],ID["EPSG",8805]],PARAMETER["False easting",500000,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8806]],PARAMETER["False northing",0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8807]]]],DERIVINGCONVERSION["Affine",METHOD["Affine parametric transformation",ID["EPSG",9624]],PARAMETER["A0",-852238.5241397796,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8623]],PARAMETER["A1",0.9696743300263966,SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],ID["EPSG",8624]],PARAMETER["A2",0.2444006826665162,SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],ID["EPSG",8625]],PARAMETER["B0",-1847553.061327294,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8639]],PARAMETER["B1",-0.2444006826665162,SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],ID["EPSG",8640]],PARAMETER["B2",0.9696743300263966,SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],ID["EPSG",8641]]],CS[Cartesian,2],AXIS["(E)",east,ORDER[1],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],AXIS["(N)",north,ORDER[2],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]]

Comment: Hans Erren thanks a bunch. I never imagined the codes to be like this.......