# Local coordinate system in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I currently need a local coordinate system for QGIS which has utm33 (https://epsg.io/32633) as starting point and is rotated by 9.73°.

- x_delta 316054.780
- y_delta 5392358.425
- rotation 9.73°

I have not managed to create a WKT code which allows the rotation with the point delta.

How can I do this?

Comment: try https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/424802/creating-non-earth-custom-projection

Comment: @JimT I do not understand where the values in the answer are coming from?
UTMX0, LON0... and I am not able to generate "Calculated Pairs" for Geoscience...

Answer (score 3):

Rotation (without scale) coefficients for the Affine parametric transformation ([EPSG:9624](https://epsg.org/coord-operation-method_9624/Affine-parametric-transformation.html)), to be included in a Derived from projected reference system, are as follows:

A1 = cos(θ)
A2 = - sin(θ)
B1 = sin(θ)
B2 = cos(θ)

In your particular case (θ=9.73°), they are:

A1 = 0.985615113
A2 = -0.169005469
B1 = 0.169005469
B2 = 0.985615113

Rotation angle is done counterclockwise. If you need the opposite, assume the angle to be -9.73°.
If you need a scale factor, multiply all rotation coefficients by it.
Also remember that translations (A0 and B0 coefficients) like rotations, are defined from the projected system to the derived one. If necessary, change the sign.

The custom projection WKT definition could be as follow:

```
DERIVEDPROJCRS["derived_from_32633",
    BASEPROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N",
        BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
            ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],
                ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            ID["EPSG",4326]],
        CONVERSION["UTM zone 33N",
            METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
                ID["EPSG",9807]],
            PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8801]],
            PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",15,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8802]],
            PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
                SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
                ID["EPSG",8805]],
            PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8806]],
            PARAMETER["False northing",0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8807]]]],
    DERIVINGCONVERSION["Affine",
        METHOD["Affine parametric transformation",
            ID["EPSG",9624]],
        PARAMETER["A0",316054.780,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8623]],
        PARAMETER["A1",0.985615113,
            SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],
            ID["EPSG",8624]],
        PARAMETER["A2",-0.169005469,
            SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],
            ID["EPSG",8625]],
        PARAMETER["B0",5392358.425,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8639]],
        PARAMETER["B1",0.169005469,
            SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],
            ID["EPSG",8640]],
        PARAMETER["B2",0.985615113,
            SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],
            ID["EPSG",8641]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The **QGIS geoscience plugin** can be used but this needs from-to coordinates.
Calculating these input corners is straightforward geometry calculus, which is best understood with the following drawing using a tilted square of 100x100meters:
[image: Layout]

With
sin 9.35 = 0.162464954
cos 9.35 = 0.986714315
gives
**corner   Mx  My  UTMx    UTMy    dx  dy**
LL  0   0   316054.780  5392358.425 0.000   0.000
LR  100 0   316153.451  5392342.179 98.671  -16.246
UL  0   100 316071.026  5392457.096 16.246  98.671
UR  100 100 316169.698  5392440.850 114.918 82.425

Use the above coordinates in [Creating Non-earth custom projection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/424802/creating-non-earth-custom-projection) to get the custom projection